# Remap Left Spacebar key on MS Sculpt ergonomic keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard, keybindings

I'm using the [Microsoft Sculpt Keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/business/sculpt-ergonomic-keyboard-for-business/5kv-00001) with my Macbook Retina, on Yosemite. This ergonomic keyboard has a split Spacebar key, like so:

[image: Split Spacebar on the MS Sculpt keyboard]

I want to remap the left Spacebar key to Backspace to simplify my typing. On Windows, a custom driver enables this remapping out of the box. However, this driver is not available on OS X.

I've already installed Karabiner and experimented with remapping keys. When I start up the EventViewer in Karabiner, both keys show up as `KeyCode::SPACE`. Is there a lower-level keycode I can access to differentiate between the left and right Spacebar keys?

Any alternate solutions are also welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I've come up with so far is to use Right-Alt as backspace. Not quite as good, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this on Sculpt Ergonomic. Only on Sculpt Comfort https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2757670/new-features-of-the-sculpt-comfort-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer:

> By default, the functions of both the left spacebar and the right
>   spacebar is to enter a space.  If you want the customized function of
>   the split space bar (where the left button acts as a backspace key and
>   the right button acts as a space-bar key), to get activated, you need
>   to **press and hold left and right space bar at the same time for more
>   than 3 seconds**.

Seems like this is an keyboard function itself, not OS.

Comment: Can you share a source? I just tried this, didn't work for me. I might be doing something wrong.